# Python IDLE disappeared from the right click context menu

Tags: windows, python

My IDLE shortcut in the right click menu has disappeared. I think it's because I used to use Python 2.7, but I installed Python 2.5 without uninstalling Python2.7, and then uninstalled Python 2.5. I found one file named `idle.bat`, and it works, but that isn't a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: I though this is because I installed two Python in my computer, then I remove one. Maybe I should try keyword like "How to insert shortcut into right-click menu". Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: That probably is the reason it went missing, but your question is how to fix it

Comment: You could try to uninstall Python using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), clean up the registry via [CCleaner free](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download), then reinstall Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a reg file to add the command to edit with IDLE for `Python.File` (.py) and `Python.NoConFile` (.pyw) file types. It's for Python 2.7, installed in `C:\Python27`, so substitute the paths to `pythonw.exe` and `idle.pyw` that are relevant to your installation. Save it to a .reg file. Then right-click and choose `Merge`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""
```

Comment: Hi, I used another way to add the right-click command, but it apply to all my files. Actually, I just want to apply to *.py file. How can I delete the right-click command I added before ? Then I can add your command. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy: You can use regedit to inspect `HKCR\*\shell`, `HKCR\*\shellex`, `HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex`, and so on. This is tedious if you don't find the culprit quickly. Or try a a context menu editor such as [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Comment: Hi, I find the command in the redgit and delete, but I still can't add the right-click command by these two command. I don't know why. I just want to add the command on the right-click menu of *.py and *.pyw file. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jimmy: When you save the above to say `idle.reg` and right-click the file `idle.reg`, do you see the option 'Merge'? If that seems to work fine and you confirm that the settings were added, then open a command prompt and check that the output of `assoc .py` is `.py=Python.File`.

Comment: Hi,actually I didn't see the idle.pyw. I see the idle.bat, so I replace idle.bat with idle.pyw.

Comment: @Jimmy: Reinstall if there's no idle.pyw in the idlelib directory. Make sure to install Tk. idle.bat is a Windows batch file that starts idle.pyw. If idle.pyw were missing, the batch file would fail.

Comment: To make this work I had to right click a .py file -->open with --> change default program to anything --> then change it back to pythonw.exe and finally the context menu items showed up

Comment: @user2682863, a .py file should open with python.exe, not pythonw.exe. Also, using Explorer to create the association probably broke passing command-line arguments to Python scripts (e.g. running `script.py arg1 arg2`). Make sure .py is associated with the `Python.File` type, which should be set to something like `"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: Yeah I verified it in the registry. Everything looked fine. It worked fine with .pyw files but this is the only way I could get .py files to work

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

---

(Also view:
[edit with idle (python gui) context menu windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168374/edit-with-idle-python-gui-context-menu-windows-7))

1. open regedit
2. go to [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command], if it doesn't exist create it.
3. copy the following line into the registry:

   "C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1"
4. go to [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\Edit with IDLE\command], if it doesn't exist create it.
5. copy the same line in the the registry:

   "C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1"

Note: if your python path is different (e.g. c:/program files/...) then change the paths to match the pythonw.exe and idle.pyw file locations.

This should also work for a clean ActivePython install (to give you that classic idle feel!).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same scenario and my fix was to re-run the installer for the current version of python that you have and choose the "repair" option.