# How to get "Edit with Idle" into the context window

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, context-menu

I have the same problem as this question here

[Python IDLE disappeared from the right click context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/343519/python-idle-disappeared-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

But I am not too sure what [Eryk Sun](https://superuser.com/users/33682/eryk-sun) is doing here.

Can somebody tell me more clearly what he is doing?

I have windows 10, python 3.8 .

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit your windows context menu by using some apps. see [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)

I think Eryk Sun is telling you to edit the registry which isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.